# Getting id of class

Tags: jquery

```
$(".eventer button[name=myBtn]").click(function() { 
console.log('clicked'); 
thisBtn = $(this); 
parent = $(this).parent(); 
num = parent.data('num'); 
id = parent.data('id'); 

if(typeof num != 'number'){ 
num = 0; 
} 
$(this).attr('disabled', true); 

$.post('javas.php', {num: (num-1), id: id}, function(data) { console.log('Ajax     success'); 

parent.next('.status').html(data); 
thisBtn.attr('disabled', false); // reset  });





console.log('Ajax success'); 
parent.data('num', --num); 
parent.next('.status').html(data); 
thisBtn.attr('disabled', false); // reset 
} );
} ); 


console.log('-- end'); 

});
```

How would i get the id of the class that has been clicked on, this is what i have so far, i want to send the id of the post along with the value of num (already being sent). How would i do this, thanks any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use `this.id` inside your handler ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the id, simply do
`var id = this.id;`

EDIT: `$(this).attr('id')` also works, but why do it the hard way? `this.id` is pure Javascript

Comment: Inside your handler. Place it after (for example) `console.log('clicked'); `

Comment: and how would i send it to the phph page

Comment: Change `$.post('javas.php',` to `$.post('javas.php?id='+id,` and you can access it with `$_GET['id']` in your script

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - open a new question for the problem above. Also, accept this answer if it is the solution to your question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the ID from the attributes:

```
var theId = $(this).attr( "id" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `attr` function:

```
id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: @MyHeadHurts ... that will return the id. But this is jQuery over-useage. Can be done without the use of jQuery at all.

Comment: I agree and have +1'd your answer

Answer (score 0):

Although class attribute in tag is called 'class' , in javascript 'class' is a reserved keyword therefore you should use:

```
 $(this).attr('className')
```